# when page resizing occurs content scrolls over header in chrome and ie8

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

when page resizing occurs content scrolls over header in chrome and ie8, it works fine in firefox and ie7?

I always want to have the content sitting at the bottom of the header not over or under

Does anyone have solution, js or css

here is a url.http://satbulsara.com/rspca/cat-page.html

Thanks,

Sat

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. Perhaps post screenshots of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is something in CSS called z-index that allows you to specify which div is on top, you can apply this to any fixed, absoute or relative div.

In your case you need to z-index your #header

```
#header {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0 60px 0;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
z-index: 99;
}
```

ta da

Comment: sorry what Im mean is I dont want to be able to scroll the content over, I always want to have sitting underneath

Comment: View it in Firefox to see what sat is trying to accomplish in Chrome and IE8